# Omnipotence Paradox

Tags: paradox

God has limitless power. So can he/she create a stone so heavy the no one lift it ? If yes, then god himself/herself can not lift it, so limited power. If no, then there's a limit to what god can create. What is the way out ?

Comment: I believe it's like comparing infinities. Since there is no limit, comparison makes no sense to begin with. However, for the sake of question, I believe the most convenient would be both things going parallelly. I mean, the weight he puts in the stone(power of creation) and  his own power to lift it. So yes, the stone can be lifted but only by god himself/herself.

Comment: This really isn't a *puzzle*.

Comment: The simplest way out is that such a god (having _absolutely_ unbounded power) just cannot exist, since his/her existence is sufficient to lead to this contradiction.

Comment: An unstoppable force and an immovable object are simply inconsistent concepts. [Irresistable Force Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irresistible_force_paradox)

Comment: Any sufficiently heavy stone will promptly collapse the entire universe into a giant black hole. Inside the black hole's point-like singularity, "up" (or any other direction, for that matter) is meaningless. Therefore, lifting doesn't exist anymore. Un-padadox't!

Answer (score 2):

> As the conclusion is a paradox, we can assume the premise is incorrect, i.e. God doesn't have limitless power ([Proof by Contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction)).